# iframe not working in cordova (android) tried cordova whitelist

Tags: android, cordova, iframe

so i'm trying to load a PDF from external source into an iframe, it works fine on desktop and mobile view but when it comes to cordova android application it doesn't load, the iframe just goes/shows blank

I've tried using cordova whitelist.

added these in config.xml

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<access origin="*" />
```

but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="QR" data-role="view" data-model="Your data model name"></div>
```

Please above code put in your HTML file

Then Below code put in your click button event

Please replace PDF url instated of "http://www.google.in";

```
//Append iframe 
$("#iframe1").find(".view-content").append('<iframe id="iframe2" src="" target="_parent"></iframe>');
var iFr1 = document.getElementById('iframe2');
iFr1.src = "http://www.google.in";
var $if1 = $("#iframe1").find("#iframe2");
$if1.load(function () {
     alert("iframe loaded");
});
```